# Размещение блоков в конце секции

Tags: html, css, responsive

Есть 3 блока. Как разместить их внизу секции  `home` например? Они в воздухе, не могу их спустить.
CSS:

```
.col-3-block {
  height: 100px;
  width: 33.333%; /* Можно задать любую другую ширину блока */
  background: grey;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.row-block {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row-block">
  <div class="col-3-block"></div>
  <div class="col-3-block"></div>
  <div class="col-3-block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: а где этот home ?

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский это чисто как пример написал, то есть у секции высота 100vh и к низу нужно прижать их

Comment: а добавить выше row-block элемент с высотой 100vh разве не будет под ним ...ммм ?

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский можете показать на примере? Не совсем понял что вы имеете ввиду. В конец класса добавить?

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/JxgrVg так ?

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский да, спасибо большое!